# fatal error call to undefined function get_header in index.php on line 1‏

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm really new to WordPress and just started learning watching video tutorials. Whenever i try to load the index.php file from my themes folder it gives a Fatal error: call to undefined function get_header() in index.php on line 1‏.
I have googled a bit and none of the solutions seems to be working it for me. I have a header.php file in the same themes folder. I DID NOT replace the index.php in the root with the index.php from the themes.
I even replaced the `get_header()` function with the following code:

```
<? if (function_exists('get_header'))
{
get_header();
}
else{
exit;
}
?>
```

In this case i get the error: "Fatal error: call to undefined function have_posts() in index.php on line 11", which is the next function after get_header. PLZZZZZZZZZZ help me with it!
Following is the full code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="contentWrap">
    <div id="content">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <?php the_time('F jS') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="postmetadata">
                        <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
                        Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
                        <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <h2>Not Found</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- end contentWrap -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div> <!-- end content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Exactly how are you 'loading the index.php'?

Comment: Just a thought.  Have you considered starting with a blank canvas type theme and editing it rather than going from scratch?  Not only is it pointless to reinvent the wheel, but it'll help alleviate basic errors like this. As you edit it it'll be clear where the errors are coming from. Or is this a child theme?

Comment: @DavidHobs `wp_head()` and `get_header()` is not the same.

Comment: I believe this is because when you navigate directly to the index.php file in your theme folder, the first thing it does it call `get_header()` because it assumes that Wordpress has already been bootstrapped, but that only happens if you visit the root index.php first. So get_header() isn't defined until after Wordpress starts up.